# JQ: Select multiple conditions

Tags: json, jq

I have a json and at the moment using select to get only the data which match one condition, I need to filter based on more conditions.

For e.g:

```
.[] | select((.processedBarsVolume <= 5) && .processedBars > 0)
```

How I can do this ?

Answer (score 508):

`jq` supports the normal Boolean operators and/or/not, so it would look like:

```
.[] | select((.processedBarsVolume <= 5) and .processedBars > 0)
```

Comment: any reason for the extra braces around `.processedBarsVolume <= 5` ?

Comment: Nope, just kept the diff with the OPs suggestion to the relevant minimum

Comment: seems unlikely to ever get the beloved checkmark at this point

Comment: Note: the and/or/not are case-sensitive. AND / OR do not work.

Comment: Abundant brackets are wise in jq. Operator precedence is a bit unintuitive if you are accustomed to imperative languages, and poorly documented in the otherwise stellar manual.

Comment: Here is the documentation for `and/or/not`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and/or/not

Answer (score 5):

I had to wrap the piping to `startswith` with parentheses in order to make this work.

```
jq -n 'env | with_entries(select ((.key|startswith("CI_")) or .key == "DOCKER_CONTAINER_VERSION_TAG"))'
```