# Extract the jq record only when match the first and last name

Tags: jq

I can get the first and birthday,

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "first": "Stevie",
      "last": "Wonder",
      "birthday": "01/01/1945"
    },
    {
      "first": "Michael",
      "last": "Jackson",
      "birthday": "03/23/1963"
    }
  ]
}
```

So with this jq command, I can get the record:

```
$ cat a.json |jq '.users[] | .first + " " + .last + " " + .birthday'
"Stevie Wonder 01/01/1945"
"Michael Jackson 03/23/1963"
```

And I am close to the answer to match the first name

```
$ cat a.json |jq '.users[] | select(.first=="Stevie") | .birthday '
"01/01/1945"
```

But how to get the output which matched both first and last name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQ: Select multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057420/jq-select-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Look up the `jq` manual for the `and` clause

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach which starts by filtering out `.users` which do not meet your criteria:

```
.users |= map(select(
  (.first == "Stevie") and (.last == "Wonder")
))
```

if you [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczBCoJAEAbg@z7FsCcXRDMrKPAFgk4dOkSHTSfaMq3dLQjz2bdx0S4hDAPz/8x3eTgXPQ1qA58MbvIeGCwxtwEDCKKT0sZClgHfWnwp5AJkVVBRyj7f1VWBmgsmhHMNPXGP8RXs6QBo/KbYUxQPUjgUHdXlvfTLj0rbcyHfXTdJYppkOZtzX7fhCL5R@Vli@a@vZX41dTXCp/E0JX6R9jztA2vZFw) you will observe it simplifies your data to just

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "first": "Stevie",
      "last": "Wonder",
      "birthday": "01/01/1945"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can add more filters if you want particular elements (e.g. .birthday):

```
  .users |= map(select(
    (.first == "Stevie") and (.last == "Wonder")
  ))
| .users[].birthday
```

to obtain
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxBC4IwGMbx@z7Fy04ORDMrKPALBJ06dBAPSxeuTGtbQZiffb0u7RLCeGH/B37nu7XBQwul4Z3Ald88LSqRG48AeMFJKm0gSYDujXhKQRnwusCh4kM/NHUhFGWEMfKGr5RmwVEqUxb8ZW2LEHWZbiDFD0DrLmbHYx51fxx6vu@D/usj22@zKMQXrRdL6ubOn8B3Mi@5qP71Lc8vuqkn@Dicx8iv4oHHm5GOfAA)

```
"01/01/1945"
```

This may seem needlessly redundant but may be easier if you are experimenting without precise requirements.